# SQL Copy Row for a list, change one column value

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert

I need to duplicate a row a couple thousand times.  I need to change one column from the copied row based on a list of ids.
Psuedo-code:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (TabID, Other Columns)
VALUES (TabID = (SELECT TabID FROM OtherTable WHERE ParentID = 1), Other Columns)
```

Is this doable?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and what you would like to get as a result?

Comment: The thing that I wanted to do was duplicate a DotNetNuke module (think User Control) to a page and all of its children pages.
So ParentID was the id of the parent page.  So the reason I wanted to copy the original row was that it had a bunch of settings that I wanted copied over with it.  I wanted to change the TabID because that is the id of the page that the User Control/Module shows up on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want to change `Tab1`?  If you wanted to increment it, for sake of argument, you could do this:

```
declare int @i
set @i = 0
while (@i < 1000)
begin
    INSERT INTO MyTable (TabID, col1, col2)
    SELECT TabID+1, col1, col2
    FROM OtherTable
    WHERE ParentID = 1 -- assuming only one row with that ID

    set @i = @i+1
end
```

A cleaner, neater way is to create a numbers table (code below untested):

```
DECLARE @numbers TABLE (n int)
declare int @i
set @i = 0
while (@i < 1000)
begin
    INSERT INTO @numbers (n) VALUES (i)
    set @i = @i+1
end

INSERT INTO MyTable (TabID, col1, col2)
SELECT TabID+1, col1, col2
FROM OtherTable
CROSS JOIN @numbers n
WHERE ParentID = 1 -- assuming only one row with that ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable
SELECT  othertable.tabid, mytable.othercolumn
FROM    mytable
CROSS JOIN
        othertable
WHERE   othertable.parentid = 1
```

This implies there is only one record with `parentid = 1` in `othertable` (otherwise your subselect would fail)

Comment: This is the kind of thing that I'm looking for....except that "WHERE parentid = 1" would return a couple thousand id's

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to using SQL Server CLR? You could write your code in C# or VB using the usual loops and get this done quite handily.

In the absence of CLR, you could compose a giant SQL string in just about any coding language, and send it to the database. That way, you could use the usual looping (for loop, do loop, foreach).

Answer (score 0):

I'll note that using the GO statement with your query, you can do things like GO 2000 and your statement will be executed 2000 times. You can insert 2000 rows that way easily. That might at least help you test and plan your solution.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableExample(thisid int IDENTITY(1,1) , thiscol varchar(1))

INSERT INTO #TableExample ( thiscol ) VALUES  ('x')
GO 2000 -- INSERT Statement will execute 2000 times.


DROP TABLE #TableExample
```

Can you explain why you need to duplicate the rows and what they will be used for? If you share those assumptions, the feedback you get might lead to changing those assumptions and ultimately lead to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve a similar problem with my 2 tables: `User` and `UserCustomSetting`. I wanted every user to inherit the settings of the "Default" user record.

I solved with a simple `CROSS JOIN`. This is my `T-SQL` query

```
DECLARE @Username VARCHAR(100) = 'DefaultUser';

--get default UserID
DECLARE @UserID INT = (SELECT UserID FROM [User] WHERE [User].Username = @Username)

-- delete previous settings (except default user)
DELETE FROM UserCustomSetting WHERE UserCustomSetting.UserID <> @UserID

-- insert new settings for all users, copy them from the default user
INSERT INTO UserCustomSetting                               
SELECT u.UserID, ucs.SettingKey, ucs.Value
FROM [User] AS u
CROSS JOIN UserCustomSetting AS ucs 
WHERE ucs.UserID = @UserID
AND u.Username <> @Username
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross joins can be difficult to get your head around. I had a similar problem on a permissions table. I wanted to copy user `1`'s permissions to a new user (10):

```
UserID      ItemID     
1           CBE17 
1           184AB
1           459FA 
1           3856D
1           A261D
```

You could add more columns if needed.

```
INSERT INTO UserPermissions (UserID, ItemID)
   SELECT 
      12, 
      ItemID 
   FROM UserPermissions WHERE RoleID = 1
```